# root can login using public key authentication but other user can't

Tags: ssh

I already use ssh-copy-id public key both as root and as user.

Everything is fine when logged in as root:

```
ssh root@192.168.31.207
Last login: Mon Oct 17 08:55:56 2022 from cn-l-200101316
[root@lab ~]#
```

But the server still asked for a password when I logged in as user.

```
ssh zhouzhendiao@192.168.31.207
zhouzhendiao@192.168.31.207's password:
```

However, I didn't need password in sshd debug mode.

I don't think this is a permission issue.By the way,I set `PubkeyAuthentication yes` and `#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Are you sure you have public and private ssh keys for the user, and the public on the remote? What are the permissions of your `.ssh` folder and key files on both client and server? Can you show the output of the `-vvv` flag to ssh command? Also, who is the user actually running those commands? Is it root or zhouzhendiao?

Comment: Thanks for reply@aviro! I used the `-vvv` flag to ssh command and found `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic, password`. I fixed by `restorecon -r -vv .ssh/authorized_keys`. It seems something corrupt. However, I still not figure out the real reason.